# Extract all numbers before the last non zero digit with VB in UiPath

Tags: vb.net, uipath, uipath-studio

I am trying to extract all numbers before the last non zero digits.

**Examples:**

1. if I have a number `4210014000000000` i am trying to extract only `4210014`.
2. and if I have a number `621788000000000` i am trying to extract only `621788`.
3. and if I have just `232322` then it should be `232322`.

Comment: Are these strings or numbers and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Assuming those *numbers* are strings, `[Number].TrimEnd('0')`. You should post the code you tried so far, so it's more clear what your dealing with (and you're also *on topic* :).

Comment: Hello, Jimi.... sorry about the flag . that was a mistake. i was trying to mark your comment as a solution instead. it worked very fine . thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that extracts all numbers before the last non zero digit. You could also convert this into a String extension as well.

```
Public Function NumbersBeforeLastNonZeroDigit(ByVal sValue As String) As String
    Return sValue.TrimEnd("0")
End Function
```

Comment: As requested by @NicoHaase, I have added a description to my answer.